# How to add KML-file routes to a Xamarin.Forms.Android google map?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some KML-files with routes that I wish to add to my map on my xamarin.forms.android project. I have created a custom renderer looking like this but now I am unsure on how to add the local kml-files (that i have in my resources folder) to the map. (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polyline-map-overlay/)

Class:

```
public class CustomMap : Map
{
    public List<Position> RouteCoordinates { get; set; }

    public CustomMap()
    {
        RouteCoordinates = new List<Position>();
    }
}
```

Renderer:

```
    GoogleMap map;
    List<Position> routeCoordinates;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            routeCoordinates = formsMap.RouteCoordinates;

            ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }


    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        map = googleMap;

        var polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

        polylineOptions.InvokeColor(0x66FF0000);

        foreach (var position in routeCoordinates)
        {
            polylineOptions.Add(new LatLng(position.Latitude, position.Longitude));
        }

        map.AddPolyline(polylineOptions);
    }
```

And this is how i use it if i want to try a route (customMap is the map i created in XAML):

```
customMap.RouteCoordinates.Add (new Position (37.785559, -122.396728));
customMap.RouteCoordinates.Add (new Position (37.780624, -122.390541));
```

But I want the KML-file to be added on the map and automatically create the route.

How would I add the KML-files to my renderer now?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Google Maps Android API Utility Library (via an Xamarin Binding library) to add/remove [KML](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml) layers to your map:

The KML can be supplied as a resource id or a stream, for the work that I do I use stream from downloaded files in the cache directory:

```
var kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(googleMap, kmlfileStream, ApplicationContext);
kmlLayer.AddLayerToMap();
```

Re: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility

Comment: Alright! Thanks a ton for this answer. I have never "binded" a library before in Xamarin. Is this a guide that goes through that https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/ ?

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Yep, that the goto guide, Jon Douglas has a great troubleshooting guide in case you get stuck on something: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: i am still working on the binding but when i did another google search i found this nuget: https://github.com/nuitsjp/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Bindings could i install that directly and make it work with that one you think?

Comment: Alright! When I tried to install it to my Xam.Forms.Android project I recieved this errormessage "Could not install package 'SushiHangover.Android.Maps.Utils 0.1.0-ci0007'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets `MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author`

Comment: I am new to this world so I am sorry for the inconvenience :) I successfully added it now! In order to use it now in my custom renderer I would need to add a "using 'packagename'" right? Thanks a ton for helping me btw.

Comment: making some progress :) had to update many things in order for the project to work with the 7.0 framework. now I get stuck with this error `expected: /Document read: document (position:END_TAG </document>@156:12 in java.io.InputStreamReader@420ba3c0)` i recieve it here `var kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(map, Resource.Raw.mykmlfile, global::Android.App.Application.Context);` . when i googled it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964317/expected-meta-read-head-positionend-tag-head1253-in-java-io-stringread it seems like it has issues reading the KML-file?

Comment: when I try the file on a "online kml-file uploader" it works there. this is one of the kml-files i use if you want to try it on ur end (uploaded on wetransfer.com): `we.tl/KNvtA1bjL0`

Comment: so If i upload that file here `http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/` it works.

Comment: I am a bit confused though. The link you posted is a PNG-image? I am working with KML-files.

Comment: alright but it should be able to read .kml files then also I assume? I tried to do it as a stream also (downloading a http-url with the .kml file) but with the same result and error.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Your KML file has mistmatched tags (i.e. the Google parser is case sensitive) once I sanitized the tags, it parsed fine. There also has a lot of other unicode junk in it but the parser ignored it, the Placemarks work fine, but the Folders are no...

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez I have some kml/xml tools that I wrote for a mapping project a while back... but it is just "text" so load it in a text editor, look for case mismatch between document/Document and folder/Folder tags....

Comment: Got it working by the way! I do not see the path though (just pins on the lat,lng points). About to create a new post with that issue. Thanks a ton for your help sir

Comment: @SushiHangover How to implement this in ios

Comment: @AswathyKR Same basic way, Google has an iOS Map Utility framework: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/kml-geojson Create an Xamarin.iOS binding library for it... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/ Someone might have a pre-existing wrapper made (check GitHub), but I just do it myself.

Comment: @SushiHangover Did you do this in xamarin.forms.ios, if those so, could you please share the code,I am new in xamarin and I don't have much idea about this.